# Sqaure progress bar with corner radius

Tags: flutter, dart

Im trying to build kind of circular squared progress bar in dart/flutter.
maybe someone knows how to make it possible? iv'e tried all, paint, border and more, but without success.

[example image - circular squared progress bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhy9Q.png)

Comment: The image you've linked to is not animated, so it's a little hard to tell what you want. I'm assuming you want the purple line on the border of the rounded square (also called a squircle) to fill up clockwise as the progress goes to 100%, is that correct?

Comment: yes just the purple border @hLk

Answer (score 4):

You can try `square_percent_indicater` package [here](https://pub.dev/packages/square_percent_indicater).

If you want a more customized widget, try `CustomPainter`:

```dart
class _MyBorderPainter extends CustomPainter {
  _MyBorderPainter(
      {required this.progress, required this.borderColor, this.strokeWdth});
  double progress; // desirable value for corners side
  double? strokeWdth;
  Color borderColor;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    double x = min(size.height, size.width);
    double x2 = x / 2;
    double x4 = x / 4;

    Paint paintt = new Paint()
      ..color = progress == 0 ? Colors.transparent : borderColor
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = strokeWdth ?? 4.0;
    // ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round;

    Path path = Path()
      ..moveTo(x2, x)
      ..lineTo(x4, x)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(0, x, 0, x - x4)
      ..lineTo(0, x4)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(0, 0, x4, 0)
      ..lineTo(x - x4, 0)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(x, 0, x, x4)
      ..lineTo(x, x - x4)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(x, x, x - x4, x)
      ..lineTo(x2, x);

    PathMetric pathMetric = path.computeMetrics().first;

    Path extractPath = pathMetric.extractPath(
        pathMetric.length * (0.5 * (1 - progress)),
        pathMetric.length * (0.5 + 0.5 * progress));
    canvas.drawPath(extractPath, paintt);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant _MyBorderPainter oldDelegate) {
    return oldDelegate.progress != progress;
  }
}

class SquareProgressBar extends StatelessWidget {
  const SquareProgressBar(
      {required this.strokeWdth,
      required this.borderColor,
      this.borderBgColor,
      required this.progress,
      this.child,
      Key? key})
      : super(key: key);
  final double strokeWdth;
  final Color borderColor;
  final Color? borderBgColor;
  final double progress;
  final Widget? child;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomPaint(
        painter: _MyBorderPainter(
            borderColor: borderBgColor ?? Colors.grey,
            strokeWdth: strokeWdth,
            progress: 1.0),
        child: CustomPaint(
          painter: _MyBorderPainter(
            progress: this.progress,
            borderColor: borderColor,
            strokeWdth: strokeWdth,
          ),
          child: this.child ?? null,
        ));
  }
}
```

which results in:

[image]

Comment: cool. i sloved it with another way of tracking after svg path. but your seems better